# Failed on startup: ExpectedArtifact matches multiple artifacts

Tags: spinnaker

I created a pipeline (KubernetesV2 provider) with a GitHub trigger that expects multiple artifacts using a regex. First stage is a bake stage using that artifact as "overrides" artifact.
If a push event is received containing multiple artifacts, the pipeline does not start with the reason
`"Failed on startup: Expected artifact ExpectedArtifact(matchArtifact=Artifact(type=github/file, name=charts/values-.*.yml... matches multiple artifacts`

I would like to to execute a pipeline instance for each of the artifacts. For now it seems to me that this cannot be done using Spinnaker alone. I could invoke a Jenkins job that again for each of the artifacts triggers a pipeline e.g. via webhook.

Could you please comment on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the override artifact need to have that same naming convention? I wonder if the workaround for this is to have the override artifact named something like override-blah-bblah.yml which then will make the spinnaker trigger think there is only one artifact found.

Comment: As of what I see in Orca's ArtifactResolver there is no chance to resolve an expected artifact using a regex that matches multiple received artifacts.
The comment on the expected artifacts area in the UI (Regex is accepted, so you could for example match on a filepath like so **name** = .*\.yaml to match all incoming YAML files.) raised my expectation that this can be used for multiple incoming artifacts but it can't.
I think I am satisfied with the situation since in a fully automated build and deploy pipeline there is only one artifact that triggers. Only thought about a manual push.